# how to check listitem is checked or not in listview android?

Tags: android, android-listview

i have listview which is multiple choice mode

```
lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, lv_items));
lView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

this contains multiple choice list items
i want to check whether selected item is checked or not 
so how i can do that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to grab the items that have been clicked and then iterate through them to find the checked ones like so:

```
// Using a List to hold the IDs, but could use an array.
List<Integer> checkedIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();                            
// Get all of the items that have been clicked - either on or off
final SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = lView.getCheckedItemPositions();                    
for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.size(); i++){
    // And this tells us the item status at the above position
    final boolean isChecked = checkedItems.valueAt(i);
    if (isChecked){
        // This tells us the item position we are looking at
        final int position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);                                             
        // Put the value of the id in our list
        checkedIDs.put(position);                                                       
    }
}
```

**Note** the getCheckedItemPositions() gets the items that have been checked by the user regardless if the checkbox was left checked or not.

Comment: lView.getCheckedItemPositions();   gives me all the checked items i want unchecked also

Comment: If you know how many items are in your listView and you know the indexes of the items that have been checked, wouldn't it be simple enough to figure out the ones that are unchecked?

Answer (score 2):

I used the isChecked property of the given list item when clicked:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    CheckedTextView item = (CheckedTextView)v;
    if(item.isChecked()){
            //do what you want
    }
```